# Dynamic javascript hovers with rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an index view with many photos.
I want to make a hover effect on each photo, but my code only places the effect on the first photo, because it doesn't have ids.

I'm not sure on how to approach. Any help please?

```
<script>
  $(".product-image").on("mouseover", function(){
    $("#product-overlay").show();
  });
  $(".product-image").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $("#product-overlay").hide();
  });
</script>
```

This will add the effect (show an overlay) on the same item everytime, and I need each item to have a unique effect.

```
<li id="product_<%= product.id %>">
        <div class="product-image">
          <%= link_to small_image(product, :itemprop => "image"), url, :itemprop => 'url' %>
          <div id="product-overlay">More</div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is the javascript in relation to the html? Any reason why you're not putting the js in the assets/javascripts/ ?

Comment: Its in the bottom of the view. I was first trying with a <script> tag before using <%= javascript_include_tag %>

Comment: @evanbikes I don't know how to pass the ids to the javascript so it knows which div to make the effect on,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is simply that you are referring to an id in your `$("#product-overlay").show()` and hide.

Try this:

```
$('.product-image').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).find('.product-overlay').show();
});
```

And then change your view to this:

```
<li id="product_<%= product.id %>">
  <div class="product-image">
    <%= link_to small_image(product, :itemprop => "image"), url, :itemprop => 'url' %>
    <div class="product-overlay">More</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Didn't realize I was using a unique id.... I will read about using this. Thank you!

Comment: @evanbikes would you mind helping me out here with a similar issue...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290487/pass-unique-ids-to-javascript-for-horizontal-scrolling