# Pass Unique-ids to Javascript for Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to develop an interface that scrolls horizontally similar to Netflix

[image: Netflix].

**Everything is displayed and works properly, BUT for some reason the Javascript only scrolls through the first Publisher's Books in the INDEX PAGE. And when I try to hover and scroll any other Publisher Books, it will only Horizontally Scroll the First Publishers Books.**

I know I have #scroll appearing many times which is why the jQuery only sees the first one.

**Does anyone know how I can pass a unique publisher_id or class so that it will work with all the publishers?**

**Models**

```
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :characters
  has_many :books, :through => :characters

end


class Character < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :publisher
  has_many :books

end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :character

end
```

**Views**

books.html.erb

```
  <%# This lists all the publishers %>
  <div class="publisherbubble">

    <% @publishers.each do |publisher| %>

      <div class = "publisherbox">
        <div class = "slider triangleBtns">

          ###renders all the books
          <%= render :partial => 'static_pages/books', :locals =>{:publisher => publisher} %>

        </div>  
      </div>

    <% end %>

  </div>
```

_books.html.erb

```
  ###How can I pass/use a unique ID or class to make this work?
  <div class="scroll-container">

      <ul class="scrollertitle">     

        <% publisher.characters.sort_by{|character| character.created_at }.each do |character|%>
          <% character.books.each do |book| %>
            <li>
              <%= link_to (image_tag book.photo(:small)), 
                  publisher_character_book_issues_path(:publisher_id => publisher.id, 
                  :character_id => character.id, :book_id => book.id ) %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

      </ul>

      <span class="previous sliderButton" data-scroll-modifier='-1'>
        <div class="arrow">
        </div>
      </span>

      <span class="next sliderButton" data-scroll-modifier='1'>
        <div class="arrow">
        </div>
      </span>

  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

    var scrollHandle = 0,
        scrollStep = 5,

        ###How can I pass/use a unique ID or class to make this work?
        parent = $(this).closest('.scroll-container');

    //Start the scrolling process
    $(".sliderButton").on("mouseenter", function () {
        var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
            direction = parseInt(data, 10);

        $(this).addClass('active');

        startScrolling(direction, scrollStep, parent);
    });

    //Kill the scrolling
    $(".sliderButton").on("mouseleave", function () {
        stopScrolling();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    //Actual handling of the scrolling
    function startScrolling(modifier, step, parent) {
        if (scrollHandle === 0) {
            scrollHandle = setInterval(function () {
                var newOffset = parent.scrollLeft() + (scrollStep * modifier);

                parent.scrollLeft(newOffset);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling() {
        clearInterval(scrollHandle);
        scrollHandle = 0;
    }

});
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll-container {
  width:auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Horizontal scrolling! I had to implement this once. It's at the bottom of this page: https://dabble.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would give the parent div a class like `scroll-container`.

Then, I would pass the parent div as an argument to `startScrolling`.

```
parent = $(this).closest('.scroll-container')
startScrolling(direction, scrollStep, parent)
```

Then, you have access to the parent and don't have to set it at the top of the js.

As an aside, if you're setting `scrollStep` at the top as a sort of configurable constant, you don't need to pass it in as an argument. `startScrolling` looks like it should work just fine without it.

As another aside, I could see `startScrolling` just taking one argument: the parent div. And the `data-modifier` could just live there instead of having to live in 2 places. And you could just get the modifier from the parent in the `startScrolling` function.

**Update**

```
$(function () {

    var scrollHandle = 0,
        scrollStep = 5;

    //Start the scrolling process
    $(".sliderButton").on("mouseenter", function () {
        var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
            direction = parseInt(data, 10);

        $(this).addClass('active');
        parent = $(this).closest('.scroll-container');
        startScrolling(direction, scrollStep, parent);
    });

    //Kill the scrolling
    $(".sliderButton").on("mouseleave", function () {
        stopScrolling();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    //Actual handling of the scrolling
    function startScrolling(modifier, step, parent) {
        if (scrollHandle === 0) {
            scrollHandle = setInterval(function () {
                var newOffset = parent.scrollLeft() + (scrollStep * modifier);

                parent.scrollLeft(newOffset);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling() {
        clearInterval(scrollHandle);
        scrollHandle = 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: I've updated the answer above as suggested, i had two questions, would this require that i change the css? Would I also need to pass the publisher_id, so that the scrolling function knows exactly what publisher to scroll?

Comment: Yes, change the css from #scroll to .scroll-container or whatever class you end up choosing. You shouldn't need to pass a publisher id since you're finding the correct parent based on the particular element that you're hovering over (closest). You should also remove the #scroll from the div; it's bad html to have more than one of the same id on a page.

Comment: yea, i've updated the code but none of it works now...:/ maybe seeing the html would help....

Comment: You almost had it. I updated the answer to include a larger context.

Comment: Ooooh gotcha. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. :)